# What is wrong with this small query? SQL errors

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this Query:

```
INSERT INTO abilities_usage (id, name, usage) 
      VALUES 
("5467", "naga_siren_mirror_image", "1") 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id='5467';
```

SQL response:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'usage) VALUES ("5467", "naga_siren_mirror_image", "1") ON
>   DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE i' at line 1

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't make sense to assign to the key if it exists... I guess what you want is this:

```
INSERT INTO abilities_usage (id, name, `usage`) 
VALUES ('5467', 'naga_siren_mirror_image', '1') 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE name = 'naga_siren_mirror_image', `usage` = '1';
```

Assuming `id` is the primary key of course. (And if it is a proper number type, don't use single-quotes for it at all).

Also, `usage` is a [reserved keyword](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html) in MySQL that you need to enclose in back-ticks.

Comment: Neat, thanks for that. However, it doesnt solve the problem. Thank you anyway, jpw!

Comment: @Atr_Max `usage` seems to be a keyword in MySQL that you need to enclose in backticks...

Comment: @Atr_Max when in doubt, escape your field and table names; even if their names are not keywords now, you never know what (even if infrequently) might get added to the list in the next version.

Comment: Thanks for that additional tip, @uueerdo! I will do that for sure in the future! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

You have to use *single* quotes for string literals:

```
INSERT INTO abilities_usage (id, name, usage) VALUES
('5467', 'naga_siren_mirror_image', '1') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id='5467';
```

Comment: INSERT INTO abilities_usage (id, name, usage) VALUES ('5467', 'naga_siren_mirror_image', '1') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id='5467'; - same error.

Comment: But you should not use single quotes for numbers. `5467` instead of `'5467'`

Comment: Removing single quotes on numbers doesnt fix that problem.